# Access other instances in the same VPC by name?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I've created few centos instances, and it seems like all of them got a internal dns records:

```
ip-{IP}.eu-central-1.compute.internal
```

However I need more helpful names, especially because IPs are changing.

I've given these instances names, by the ec2 console, and by running `hostnamectl set-hostname {HOST} --static`, but even then, these names doesn't get registered on the internal DNS service.

I want these hostnames to be registered automatically, as these internal IPs are changing.

How can I get it to work?

Comment: [Route 53 private hosted zones](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html) should do this.

Comment: @Tim *"I want these hostnames to be registered automatically."*

Comment: I guess that part is a bit tricky. I made a comment rather than an answer as it was more of a place to start looking rather than something I knew 100% would work.

Comment: User data that updates a route53 private zone with the ip address of an instance.

Comment: I know that in windows systems, the client registers its hostname on the dns server, so called "dynamic record". I do not believe this is a windows-only thing and looks like it supposes to be implemented without writing some weird zone updating scripts...